# Process multiple columns with Pandas apply method when columns are not predefined

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a general function to process all columns that start with something. The caveat being that I don't know how many columns will start with that thing beforehand.

For example, I would like to just process columns that start with "dog":

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2,5], [1, 3,4], [4, 6,1]], columns=['dog1', 'cat1','dog2'])
```

Returns

```
    dog1    cat1    dog2
0   1          2    5
1   1          3    4
2   4          6    1
```

I can create a list of those columns:

```
col_list = []
for col in df.columns:
    if col.startswith('dog'):
        col_list.append(col)
col_list
```

Returns

```
['dog1', 'dog2']
```

In this example I use apply to process the things in that list by specifying them individually. The answer I'm looking for would use the list. This is just to show how I am using apply now.

Also, I would like to apply more complex functions than summing so I'm looking to be able to apply general functions. Summing the two columns with a function is just for the purposes of the example.

```
def sum_dogs(d1,d2):
    return d1+d2

df['sum_dogs'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum_dogs(x['dog1'],x['dog2']),axis=1)
```

Returns

```
    dog1    cat1    dog2    sum_dogs
0      1    2          5    6
1      1    3          4    5
2      4    6          1    5
```

I would like to apply whatever the output of "col_list" may return for any DataFrame.

---

ANSWER from RafaelC below:
I just wanted to show how the answer is used to solve my (confusing) example :).

```
def sum_dogs(col_list):
    sum = 0
    for col in col_list:        
        sum = sum+col
    return sum

df['sum_dogs'] = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('dog')].agg(sum_dogs, 1)
```

Comment: Is your function vectorisable or do you require use of `pd.DataFrame.apply`. `apply` + `lambda` will be unavoidably slow if performance is an issue.

Comment: `df.assign(sum_dogs=df[col_list].sum(axis=1)`?

Comment: @PMende, I'm guessing the *real* function might not be a simple sum, which is why I think we need more clarity.

Comment: @roganjosh Huh? "I would like to apply whatever the output of "col_list" may return for any DataFrame."

Comment: @PMende, yes the real function is not a simple sum, I only used that as an example. I'll clarify more in my question, thanks.

Comment: @jpp, I'm just looking to use the apply function on a list of columns, the construction of the list is not important in this example besides to show that I'm pulling a list of columns from a DataFrame.

Comment: @PMende, In my example I used apply to do what I wanted without using the list. I just did that to show how I was using apply. I added (without using the list) to show that I was not solving the problem in the way that the question describes.

Comment: @PMende I definitely read this question differently before the edit. You're right.

Comment: @sparrow If you're looking to use a more complex function, you'll need to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a shot here, you can use `.loc[:, cols]` to slice only columns that matter, and `.agg` in axis 1 to perform your logic

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('dog')].agg(function, 1)
```

For a simple sum, for example, this can be

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('dog')].agg(sum, 1) # or sum(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use apply?
Showing a methods that provide a multitude of results.
Perhaps this is more what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2,3], [2, 3,4], [3, 4,5]], columns=['dog1', 'cat1','dog2'])
lookfor = 'dog'
col_list = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith(lookfor)]

def col_sum(col_list):
    return col_list.sum(axis=1)

def col_collective(col_list):
    return(col_list.values.tolist())

def sum_text(col_list):
    val = col_list.sum(axis=1)
    for i in range(len(val)):
        val[i] = f'{val[i]} {lookfor}s'
    return val

def allthelittleones(col_list):
    val = col_list.sum(axis=1)
    for i in range(len(val)):
        val[i] = str([1,]*val[i])
    return val

df['sum_'+lookfor] = col_sum(df[col_list])
df['collective_'+lookfor] = col_collective(df[col_list])
df['sumtext_'+lookfor] = sum_text(df[col_list])
df['alltheones_'+lookfor] = allthelittleones(df[col_list])

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, in my example I use summing the two columns, but I would like to apply more complex functions to col_list.

Comment: Ok.  Can you give an example of a more complex function that you would use?  My example here is very column independent.  Just change the lookfor variable.  Also, you can create the column list like this instead of looping.

Comment: Yes, that's a more elegant way of constructing the list, thanks! The complexity of the function is not important for this question since I'm looking for a general way to process the columns without having to use built in functions.